# Make material ui SwipeableDrawer draggable even on desktop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mern

I added swipeable drawer based on the [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/#swipeable-edge):

> Swipeable You can make the drawer swipeable with the SwipeableDrawer
> component.
>
> This component comes with a 2 kB gzipped payload overhead. Some
> low-end mobile devices won't be able to follow the fingers at 60 FPS.
> You can use the disableBackdropTransition prop to help.

```
{(['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'] as const).map((anchor) => (
  <React.Fragment key={anchor}>
    <Button onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)}>{anchor}</Button>
    <SwipeableDrawer
      anchor={anchor}
      open={state[anchor]}
      onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
      onOpen={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)}
    >
      {list(anchor)}
    </SwipeableDrawer>
  </React.Fragment>
))}
```

The problem with this is that it's only draggable on mobile device. Is it possible to make it draggable on desktop?
Like the user clicks on the edge with the cursor and drags the drawer to close or open it.

Especially, by adding an edge that the user can click on with the cursor:

> Swipeable edge You can configure the SwipeableDrawer to have a visible
> edge when closed.
>
> If you are on a desktop, you can toggle the drawer with the "OPEN"
> button. If you are on mobile, you can open the demo in CodeSandbox
> ("edit" icon) and swipe.

[image]

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Global } from '@emotion/react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import { grey } from '@mui/material/colors';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Skeleton from '@mui/material/Skeleton';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import SwipeableDrawer from '@mui/material/SwipeableDrawer';

const drawerBleeding = 56;

const Root = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  height: '100%',
  backgroundColor:
    theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? grey[100] : theme.palette.background.default,
}));

const StyledBox = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? '#fff' : grey[800],
}));

const Puller = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
  width: 30,
  height: 6,
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? grey[300] : grey[900],
  borderRadius: 3,
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 8,
  left: 'calc(50% - 15px)',
}));

function SwipeableEdgeDrawer(props) {
  const { window } = props;
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleDrawer = (newOpen) => () => {
    setOpen(newOpen);
  };

  // This is used only for the example
  const container = window !== undefined ? () => window().document.body : undefined;

  return (
    <Root>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Global
        styles={{
          '.MuiDrawer-root > .MuiPaper-root': {
            height: `calc(50% - ${drawerBleeding}px)`,
            overflow: 'visible',
          },
        }}
      />
      <Box sx={{ textAlign: 'center', pt: 1 }}>
        <Button onClick={toggleDrawer(true)}>Open</Button>
      </Box>
      <SwipeableDrawer
        container={container}
        anchor="bottom"
        open={open}
        onClose={toggleDrawer(false)}
        onOpen={toggleDrawer(true)}
        swipeAreaWidth={drawerBleeding}
        disableSwipeToOpen={false}
        ModalProps={{
          keepMounted: true,
        }}
      >
        <StyledBox
          sx={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: -drawerBleeding,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 8,
            borderTopRightRadius: 8,
            visibility: 'visible',
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
          }}
        >
          <Puller />
          <Typography sx={{ p: 2, color: 'text.secondary' }}>51 results</Typography>
        </StyledBox>
        <StyledBox
          sx={{
            px: 2,
            pb: 2,
            height: '100%',
            overflow: 'auto',
          }}
        >
          <Skeleton variant="rectangular" height="100%" />
        </StyledBox>
      </SwipeableDrawer>
    </Root>
  );
}

SwipeableEdgeDrawer.propTypes = {
  /**
   * Injected by the documentation to work in an iframe.
   * You won't need it on your project.
   */
  window: PropTypes.func,
};

export default SwipeableEdgeDrawer;
```

Comment: Somebody opened a feature request and you can upvote it: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/35680